# Datatypes and application has stopped

Tags: java, android, types

I've this part of code:

```
public void onClickHandler(View a) {
    String pressed = null;
    String actual_text = null;
    String new_text = null;
    char last_char; //or char last_char = (Character) null; - the same problem
    int bla;

    pressed=((Button)a).getText().toString(); 

    EditText lifeView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    actual_text = lifeView.getText().toString();

    bla=actual_text.length()-1;
    last_char = actual_text.charAt(bla);
}
```

And I'm solving the problem, that after pressed button I will get the error "The application  has stopped unexpectedly. Please try it again."

The problem is on the line "char last_char" -- but I don't know why, Eclipse does not report a fault too...

Comment: I have not set logcat yet... but the problem in the line with "char last_char" (manually debug)

Comment: Could you give the stacktrace you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the `char last_char;`

Ex:

```
char last_char=' ';
```

or similar but not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try initilizing local variable `char last_char;`